# ASP.Net Check Box Control checked or not in code behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use checkbox control in asp.net c# where I am facing an issue when I checked the checkbox and wants to display its text to the label control but it hasn't work.

Also I searched about it over google and here too but no use.

Here is my code

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
            Label1.Text = "hello";
        else
            Label1.Text = "hi";
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated
Please help me and
Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you wiring up the event-handler? This will only work if your form automatically does a postback when the checkbox is clicked by the user (and your users WILL hate you for this): but I recommend that you should **not** use "server-side event handlers" for client-side events in WebForms.

Comment: so how can i use this.?

Comment: Don't use it. Write code in JavaScript that runs in the browser instead. (BTW, WebForms is dead: the latest version of ASP.NET does not support WebForms at all and hasn't done for the past 2 years now).

Comment: OK thanks for giving me the idea.
And also thanks for fast replying

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure that the AutoPostBack property of the CheckBox is set to true.
Also, this CheckBox might be inside an updatePanel and Label1 is not in an updatePanel.